# Shallow water equations with moving body

Tags: numerical-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I was wondering if there are any shallow water equation solvers out there that can include rigid body motion for the surface the water flows on?

Comment: What do you mean by "rigid motion for the surface"? Have you checked [ClawPack](http://www.clawpack.org/)?

Comment: Are you interested in flow in a ship?  We may need more context before we are able to give a recommendation beyond @nicoguaro's suggestion.

Comment: Flow on the deck of a ship yes. Have not checked out ClawPack yet!